# JSON list optimization

Tags: javascript, json

I want to create a JSON API that returns a list of objects. Each object has an id, a name and some other information. API is consumed using JavaScript.

The natural options for my JSON output seems to be:

```
"myList": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "object1",
    "details": {}
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "object2",
    "details": {}
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "object3",
    "details": {}
  },
]
```

Now let's imagine that I use my API to get all the objects but want to first do something with id2 then something else with id1 and id3.

Then I may be interested to be able to directly get the object for a specific id:

```
"myList": {
  "1": {
    "name": "object1",
    "details": {}
  },
  "2": {
    "name": "object2",
    "details": {}
  },
  "3": {
    "name": "object3",
    "details": {}
  },
}
```

This second option may be less natural when somewhere else in the code I want to simply loop through all the elements.

Is there a good practice for these use cases when the API is used for both looping through all elements and sometime using specific elements only (without doing a dedicated call for each element)?

Comment: How to read the JSON with any language/framework is of no importance here. I just want to discuss optimization for lists in JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you've changed the ID value from `1` to `id1`. This would make operating on the data a bit annoying, because you have to add and remove `id` all the time.

If you didn't do that, and you were relying on the sorted order of the object, you may be in for a surprise, depending on JS engine:

```
var source = JSON.stringify({z: "first", a: "second", 0: "third"});
var parsed = JSON.parse(source);
console.log(Object.keys(parsed));
// ["0", "z", "a"]
```

My experience is to work with arrays on the transport layer and index the data (i.e. convert array to map) when required.

Comment: I am trying to understand but it seems you have done the contrary here: using object on the transport layer and getting an array after? I have updated my question removing the "idX" has I get it is condusing.

Comment: The example code in my answer is supposed to show you that the order you put data in [z, a, 0] is not necessarily the order you got out [0, z, a]. So if you're working with ordered lists, don't rely on objects.

Comment: Oh great I get it. So your answer is that it is preferable to expose arrays for an API. Then you can still map each element when using the API if necessary. Thanks.